# Nodejs+webRTC chat web widget

Tags: node.js, webrtc

My requirement is I have one chat application using webRTC and nodejs. Now I have to develop web widget for a chat module so user can easily integrate that widget with its website. I have no experienced with chat widget using nodejs and webrtc.

Comment: Do you actually have a question or do you just want people to program for you?

Comment: Yes I have actually question about it. why ? I have not experieced chat widget with nodejs and webrtc kind application or any others

Comment: There is not a single question in your "question" just some of your personal requirements and stating you have no experience.

Comment: Sorry It is my mistake Benjamin Trent. Please just suggest me what to do in my case ?

Comment: Work on it, do your own research, go to forums(SO is not a forum btw), and when you have a specific programming question, post it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have experience with web widgets, a bit of light reading may be in order; you can try this: 
http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/